# How to update BindingList item without effect other list item?

Tags: c#, list, collections, binding

I have a binding list `AttachDocumentList` that is store attachment document items and I already assign this binding list to object `CurrentMessage` property (`CurrentMessage.AttachDocument`) and I add `CurrentMessage` object to `_messageList` to store the collection of `CurrentMessage`.

When I update a 
`BindingList AttachDocumentList` the object `CurrentMessage`'s property in that is already stored in `_messageList` is update too.

So how can I update `Bindinglist AttachmentDocumentList` without affecting `_messageList` item?

```
public BindingList<AttachDocument> AttachDocumentList { get; set; }

public MessageModel CurrentMessage { get; set; }

private List<MessageModel> _messageList = new List<MessageModel>();

CurrentMessage.AttachDocument = new BindingList<AttachDocument>(AttachDocumentList);

_messageList.Add(new MessageModel(CurrentMessage));
```

Comment: I think you will find it has to do with you assigning a reference (by ref) and so you need to clone the object before adding it to _messageList but it would be a lot easier to answer if you put together a working, compileable example

Comment: and how to pass it by value?

Comment: I already create a clone new object before save to list by using copy constructor

Comment: as I said, a working example that shows this might help.